# Angular: How to handle a null ElementRef?

Tags: angular, elementref

In an Angular component, I display real-time data in a very complex way that requires the use of `ElementRef` for various purposes supporting UI interaction.

```
this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-element')
```

As a result, I am running into a few rare use cases when referencing an element this way throws a `null` error because the element is either not yet accessible in the DOM or had been previously removed due to real-time data updates inside an `*ngFor`.

To prevent errors, I am checking the native element for `null`:

```
if(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-elment') != null) {
  // reference or set style on this element
}
```

This works fine, but is there a better approach? I have wound up with a lot of these `if` statements throughout my component as a result.

I have made every effort to avoid touching the DOM and to avoid running into the possibility for an element to be `null` otherwise in my template, but I am stuck with some rare cases that are just unavoidable.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, try to eliminate or minimize the use of `ElementRef`. The [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) docs state:

> Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead. Alternatively you can take a look at [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported.
>
> Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling between your application and rendering layers which will make it impossible to separate the two and deploy your application into a web worker.

If an `ElementRef` is unavoidable and there are cases where the `ElementRef` will be `null`, then the best you can do (without resorting to added complexity) is to use a little syntactic sugar and refactoring.

**1. Use a short variable reference**

```
const myEl = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-elment');
    
if (myEl != null) { }
```

**2. Use a `notNull()` function to make code cleaner and refactor logic that requires the `ElementRef` into a subroutine.**

```
export function notNull(x: any): boolean {
  return x != null
}


const myEl = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-elment');
    
notNull(myEl) ? doSomething(myEl) : false;
```